# How can I tell ubuntu to use only the external monitor?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, monitor

I use ubuntu 14 with an external monitor. It seems there is some problem with the internal graphics so I want to tell ubuntu to use only the external monitor which is connected with hdmi. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two possible options:

1. Using the special **function key** on your keyboard (e.g. Fn+F8) to
   switch between using one or the other or both
2. **Session Menu** > **System Settings** > **Hardware** / **Displays**

Answer (score 1):

you can use `xrandr` command

`xrandr`

This is mine

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2646 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1366x768+1280+57 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768       59.8*+
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
DVI-I-2 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

will show you a list of the connected monitors and the resolutions that they support.

The names between the ** are the screen names.

Choose yours to make default "you say the hdmi connected"
 then run the command

```
  xrandr --output SCREEN_NAME --primary
```

This will make the SCREEN_NAME as default monitor which will stored even after reboots.